# What is the difference in 一点儿都不贵 with and without the 都?

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference

What is the difference if we say:

> 一点儿**都**不贵

or *without* the **都** (i.e., 一点儿不贵)?

Comment: 一点儿不贵 is a stilted version of 一点儿都不贵 or 一点儿也不贵.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't find the sentence without 都 to be natural. You might substitute it with 也, and both would be entirely equal to the expressed meaning.

In fact, 一点儿不贵 sound like 'a little not expensive' rather than your intended meaning of 'not at all expensive'.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, no difference at all. I know someone may try to explain their difference by the significance of 都. But no Chinese are willing to consider it before making use of it.
They are both from spoken Chinese and consequently can not be used in some writing tasks. If it were me, I would use the former one. Because it sounds more casual and nature.

Answer (score 0):

In here, 都 means "at all (compared with something similar)" - everybody understands that "Not expansive at all!" is a comparative term/speaking, the logic is clear.

Without it, the logic behind "Not expansive!" is unclear, thus it can be considered a local/personal informal expression, which shall be avoided either in writing or speaking.